# ListView setOnItemListener

Tags: java, android, listview

У меня есть Леяут и в нем контейнер для списка (preferances) со вложенным списком, я хочу обработать именно вложенный список, как так сделать?

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity{
    SharedPreferences sp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);



        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//events here....
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Код xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/liner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:background="#1c78e8">
        ></LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Вам надо определиться чего вы таки хотите: использовать готовое гугловое решение для активити с настройками или пилить своё решение этой проблемы. Вы же, похоже, хотите как-то это совместить. Зачем? И что у вас на экране отображается? И что не срабатывает? Вопрос непонятен и подход у вас какой-то странный.

Comment: я не весь код леяута показал, я хочу сделать кастомный леяут, я не пойму почему я не могу  обратиться так:  ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list); Он его просто не видит

Comment: Во первых `addPreferencesFromResource` устарел и его не рекомендуется использовать в активити. Его надо во фрагментах использовать. Во вторых неизвестно что происходит при совместном использовании этого метода с последующим вызовом `setContentView`. В третьих попробуте другой `id` назначить для списка. Например просто `android:id="@+id/list"` и находить его соответственно `findViewById(R.id.list)`

Comment: я уже менял id но при переходе на эту активность вылетает, а в логи пишет что нужно писать  android:id="@android:id/list"

Comment: Видать это из-за особенностей `PreferenceActivity`, коя должна содержать в стандартной разметке такой список для отображения настроек из `xml`. Повторю: вам надо или делать обычную активити и в ней реализовывать с нуля работу с настройками или использовать `PreferenceActivity` стандартным способом - т.е. не использовать там свою разметку.

Answer (score 1):

Во первых `addPreferencesFromResource` устарел и его не рекомендуется использовать в активити. Его надо во фрагментах использовать. Во вторых неизвестно что происходит при совместном использовании этого метода с последующим вызовом `setContentView`.

Так что проблема, видать, из-за особенностей `PreferenceActivity`, коя должна содержать в стандартной разметке такой список для отображения настроек из `xml`. Вам надо или делать обычную активити и в ней реализовывать с нуля работу с настройками или использовать `PreferenceActivity` стандартным способом - т.е. не использовать там свою разметку